# Preposition/phrase for "to go outside"

Tags: preposition, phrase

> I want to go outside.

Do we say

> (a) Ich will nach draußen gehen.
>
> (b) Ich will zu draußen gehen.

or others?

Comment: I believe A is the right one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is

> Ich will nach draussen gehen.

All those preposition based locational adverbs work that way... *drin*, *links*, *rechts*, *oben*, *unten* etc.

Or a shorter version is:

> Ich will rausgehen/raus gehen.

If you're talking about going for a walk or get some fresh air, then this would be the more idiomatic choice. The first one is more suitable if you're talking about the outside of a particular venue.

Comment: Are you Swiss, @Emanuel? Because otherwise it's "draußen", and not "draussen".

Comment: @Elena... not Swiss... just ignorant :)